# Dust.Js sections and paths

Tags: json, dust.js

I get a error JSON in following format

```
error = [{field:'one', desc:'This is error for field one', value='FromPostFieldOne'},
         {field:'two', desc:'This is error for field two', value='FromPostFieldTwo'}];
```

which I want to display in following template

```
{#error}
<form>
  <input type="text" name="one" id="one" value="<!- value for field one from JSON-->"/>
  <!-- Display error from JSON for field one here -->

  <input type="text" name="two" id="two" value="<!- value for field two from JSON -->"/>
  <!-- Display error from JSON for field two here -->

</form>
{/error}
```

I am not able to figure if I achieve this with ether "Explicit context setting" or "{@if cond="condition"} helper". All examples on Linkedin Dust site illustrate how to do this with JSON key values but not object arrays.

Help appreciated !!!!

Answer (score 1):

your json is not valid you should make something like this:

```
 error = [
          {
           field:'one', 
           desc:'This is error for field one', 
           value:'FromPostFieldOne'
          },
          {
           field:'two', 
           desc:'This is error for field two', 
           value:'FromPostFieldTwo'}
         ];
```